# Hilbert-Huang Transform Implementation

Tags: frequency, transform, real-time, hilbert-transform, java

I am looking for a implementation of Hilbert-Huang Transformation. Ideally, in Java, but any language with similar syntax would prove useful. Could someone point me to a specific implementation, preferably in Java?

Comment: Well, this looks like more of a Programming question. Anyway let us see if anyone has a link for the implementation.

Comment: First hit on a Google search: http://code.google.com/p/hilbert-huang-transform/source/browse/trunk/src/hht/EMD.java

Comment: I need it too. do you know any other method with time,frequency localization. apart from HHT,wavelet? tnx

Comment: @PaulR The code that you linked doesn't even compile in Eclipse.

Comment: Maybe you could fix the compile errors, or try one of the other results from a Google search ? Or do you just want a complete working "black box" solution, in which case StackOverflow is probably a better place to ask ?

Comment: I tried translating the code, but I don't know anything about pointers. I did google searches and I can't find anything written in Java or a similar syntactic language. I wouldn't mind a black box solution, but alas, I can't find even that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hilbert-Huang starts with empirical mode decomposition (EMD). I know one HHT code is available on Matlab central but I personally find it not very robust and extremely sensitive to edge effects. A more robust solution may be found here : http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/patrick.flandrin/emd.html

Once the EMD is performed, the missing step to complete HHT is the Hilbert transform which is fairly straight forward.

More details and links are mentioned in [this post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10560/precisions-on-hilbert-huang-transform).

Answer (score 1):

Python implementation of the EMD is available at https://github.com/jaidevd/pyhht
It is a good package with examples of the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to take a look at Python version PyEMD available either from [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/EMD-signal) or [GitHub](https://github.com/laszukdawid/PyEMD). If you prefer you can simply install it from command line using

```
pip install EMD-signal
```

or

```
git clone https://github.com/laszukdawid/PyEMD
cd PyEMD
python setup.py install
```